# Using Schengen visa to enter Mexico

Tags: visas, schengen, customs-and-immigration, mexico, vietnamese-citizens

I have a valid Schengen visa in my Vietnamese passport. Can I use a Schengen Visa (Tourism) to visit Mexico ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As stated by Timatic, the database used by airlines, [**yes you can**](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=vn&DE=mx&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX).

> Visa required, **except** for passengers with a valid visa issued
>   by Canada, Japan, USA, United Kingdom or **a Schengen Member
>   State** for a maximum stay of 180 days

Note that the [official immigration website](http://www.inm.gob.mx/gobmx/word/index.php/paises-requieren-visa-para-mexico/) is outdated, only stating that Schengen permanent residents, and not visa holders, are visa-exempt.

Comment: Crazydre, are you sure about that, Can you please post the link ?

Comment: @Suzi Click on "Yes you can", that's a link to Timatic, the database used by airlines

Comment: @Suzi If this satisfies you, please upvote the answer (up arrow) and accept it (button below down arrow)

Comment: This answer could be improved by adding a link to an official government source, since getting on the plane is only half the battle.  Also, having both links will be helpful if the policy changes in the (presumably distant) future.

Comment: @phoog Timatic is pretty authoritative. Airlines use it to know who they can allow to board and, since they'll get fined a lot of money if they keep bringing people to Mexico without the proper visas, they have a strong motivation to keep it accurate.

Comment: @DavidRicherby If only it didn't suck at clarifying transit requirements for most countries - which has got me in a rather precarious situation (but that's another story of course)

Comment: @DavidRicherby sure, I know that, but imagine yourself having a dispute with a border official about whether your documents are adequate. Which do you think has more authority: "Timatic says..." or "your government's website says..."?  Timatic may be trustworthy and authoritative, but it's still one step removed from the source and therefore less authoritative.

Comment: Note that you'll still need to fly directly to Mexico, or have a visa for the US or Canada if you are transiting from there.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid You can fly through anywhere in Europe

Comment: @phoog The gob.mx site is bloody outdated :( Still says only permanent residents, and not visa holders, are visa-exempt. In my experience, however, in these situations requesting to see the supervisor normally helps

Comment: @Crazydre okay, then the answer could be improved by noting that the government site is out of date :-).  Sorry to keep harping on this, but it just seems critical to me that one acknowledge official sources for questions about legal issues like this.

Comment: JFTR, as of Oct 5 the Mexico government website continues to say _permanent resident_ of UK, Canada, Japan, or Schengen. Any valid visa for the USA is acceptable.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus ...while Timatic still says visas from all of the above are OK. Many countries frequently fail to update their websites - South Korea is the same.

Comment: Is thee a date on the website?  If not, how can you know that the website is outdated?  Perhaps Timatic is wrong.

Comment: @WGroleau They've been liberalising the regime, not toughening it, which your hypothesis would imply.